# How Widespread is Silverlight in the Corporate World?

Tags: silverlight

I would like to develop an application using Silverlight. As this application is used to give demos to delegates on their corporate networks, I would like to know how widespread  Silverlight is?

Could anyone please let me know the coverage of Silverlight in the corporate world?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Do you mean market penetration? Plugin availability depending on the browser?...

Comment: Hi, I would like to know a rough percentage of silverlight installed computers in corporate networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [the place to go](http://www.riastats.com/) if you want such statistics

(it's down at the moment but will come back soon)

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way to know without someone taking a manual survey, as Corporate traffic is not separated from overall web traffic (how would you identify it?).

The current figure for Silverlight in overall browser use it around 60%, but due to security requirements, IT update procedures etc, it may well be closer to either 100% or 0% at specific companies.

I think you can assume it would be installed *if a specific business need arises*. Best for you to speak to the specific companies you are targetting :)